# can't change filltext () to fillRect in html5 multiplayer game

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Iam using html5, javascript and node js to make this game ..you can find the link of it here
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/green-snake?path=index.html:47:6 )))-> so what I need to do is changing the fillText() method to fillRect() method in index.html line '48' but it doesn't work
from ctx.fillText ('p', data[].x, data[].y); to 
ctx fillRect ();

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please, review the help section starting by https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then edit your question, include the relevant parts of your code directly in the question and format all of this correctly (see format helpers at left of edit screen). "Doesnt' work" is **never** a good description of your problem so be more explicit, include error messages or current output compared to the expected one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking up the docs on [FillRect](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillrect.asp). Since I'm assuming FillText works it's not a problem with the canvas, gameLoop, or clearing. It's probably incorrect syntax or something.

This is the code:

```
  ctx.fillRect(data[i].x, data[i].y, width, height);
```

strokeRect works the same way:

```
 ctx.strokeRect(data[i].x, data[i].y, width, height);
```